# Trigger at Database Level on DDL Statments

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ddl

How to create a database level trigger on DDL statements in Microsoft SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A nice example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187909.aspx)

```
USE YourDatabase;
GO
CREATE TABLE ddl_log (PostTime datetime, DB_User nvarchar(100), Event nvarchar(100), TSQL nvarchar(2000));
GO
CREATE TRIGGER log 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS 
AS
DECLARE @data XML
SET @data = EVENTDATA()
INSERT ddl_log 
   (PostTime, DB_User, Event, TSQL) 
   VALUES 
   (GETDATE(), 
   CONVERT(nvarchar(100), CURRENT_USER), 
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'), 
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)') ) ;
GO
--Test the trigger
CREATE TABLE TestTable (a int)
DROP TABLE TestTable ;
GO
SELECT * FROM ddl_log ;
GO
```