# SQL way to save history of commands done?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hi I have a database where we often need to delete records, however as this can sometimes be mistakenly done I was wondering is there a way to save a sort of history of SQL commands done, and the output to screen log of them? Thanks

Comment: The answer highly depends on the RDBMS you're using, so you should add that information to your question.

Comment: Apologies it's SQL Server

Comment: No problem. I've re-tagged the question accordingly.

Comment: How about something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672350/how-to-create-a-trigger-that-would-save-the-deleted-data-multiple-records-to-a and save deleted records to a separate table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
USE YourDatabase;
GO
CREATE TABLE ddl_log (PostTime datetime, DB_User nvarchar(100), Event nvarchar(100), TSQL nvarchar(2000));
GO
CREATE TRIGGER log 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS 
AS
DECLARE @data XML
SET @data = EVENTDATA()
INSERT ddl_log 
   (PostTime, DB_User, Event, TSQL) 
   VALUES 
   (GETDATE(), 
   CONVERT(nvarchar(100), CURRENT_USER), 
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'), 
   @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)') ) ;
GO
--Test the trigger
CREATE TABLE TestTable (a int)
DROP TABLE TestTable ;
GO
SELECT * FROM ddl_log ;
GO
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936012/trigger-at-database-level-on-ddl-statments)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Sql Server. 
You can write a trigger as someone suggest or you can configure Change Data Capture. CDC will have better performance.